# How to convert columns into matrix and table stored in list by complex conditions [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, data-conversion, purrr

I have a data frame which contains households' information on their trips in a day.

```
df <- data.frame(
hid=c("10001","10001","10001","10001"),
mid=c(1,2,3,4),
thc=c("010","01010","0","02030"),
mdc=c("000","01010","0","02020"),
thc1=c(0,0,0,0),
thc2=c(1,1,NA,2),
thc3=c(0,0,NA,0),
thc4=c(NA,1,0,3),
thc5=c(NA,0,NA,0),
mdc1=c(0,0,0,0),
mdc2=c(0,1,NA,2),
mdc3=c(0,0,NA,0),
mdc4=c(NA,1,NA,2),
mdc5=c(NA,0,NA,0)
)
```

`hid`: household id (actual data frame has further households)  
`mid`: household member id  
`thc`: strings to indicate sequence of member's daily movement;  
0=inside house, 1=unique ID of the place s/he visited

Thus, if it's coded as `01020`, it means that s/he visited place `1` from home (0) then backed to home (0), visited another place `2` from home (0) then backed to home (0) in a day.

IDs in `hid` are splitted into each columns, `htc1`, `htc2`, `htc3`, `htc4` and `htc5`. Maximum number of `thc` is set based on the maximum length of the movement in a household.  
If maximum code is 5 in a member and those of others are 3, `htc4` and 'htc5' of other members are padded by `NA`.

`mdc`: variable which indicates attribute of the activity taken at the place. For instance, 1=work and 2= school. It is also splitted in the latter columns.

Now, what I am trying to obtain is a list which contains `adjacency matrix` and `node list` for `network analysis` used in, i.e., `igraph`, which contains information in the `df`.

This is the desired outcome:

```
# Desired list
[1] # It represents first element grouped by `hid`.
    # In the actual data frame, there are around 40,000
    # households which contains different `hid`.

$hid # `hid` of each record
[1]10001
[2]10001
[3]10001
[4]10001

$mid # `mid` of each record
[1]1
[2]2
[3]3
[4]4

$trip # `adjacency matrix` of each `mid`
      # head of line indicates destination area id
      # leftmost column indicates origin area id
      # for example of [1], 'mid'=1 took 1 trip from 0 to 1 and 1 trip from 1 to 0
[1] # It represents `mid`=1
  0 1
0 0 1
1 1 0
[2] # It represents `mid`=2 
  0 1
0 0 2
1 2 0
[3]
  0
0 0
[4]
  0 1 2 3
0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0

$node # Attribute of each area defined in `mdc'
      # for instance, mdc of `mid`=4, that is `02020`, s/he had activity `2` twice
      # in area id '2' and `3` as indicated in `thc` and `thc1-4`.
      # The number does not indicate "how many times s/he took activity in the area"
     # but indicates "what s/he did in the area"
area mdc1 mdc2 mdc3 mdc4
   0   0    0    0     0
   1   0    1   NA    NA
   2  NA   NA   NA     2
   3  NA   NA   NA     2

[2] # Next element continues same information of other hid
    # Thus, from `hid` to `mdc` are one set of attributes of one element
```

It is quite complecated to convert from `df` to desired list in my current knowledge of list and data conversion. For instance, to create `adjacency matrix`, I need to refer information in `thc or thc1-5` anteroposteriorly. For `node`, it also require to obtain the maximum number of area id and store information in 'mdc or mdc1-5'.  
I highly appreciate if you could provide any suggestions to start with this work.

I prefer to use `tidyverse`, `purrr` and their families but I have not used `purrr` for list operation. I used to use the formater for data manipulation but not familior with list operation.

After this operation, I will visualize movement and activity pattern of each household (not member) in `igraph` or other packages such as `ggnetwork` or `networkD3` to find ascendant pattern from distribution of each pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two helper functions that can build the adjacency matrix and the activity matrix:## Build the adjacency matrices (details in comments)

```
build_adj_mat <- function(thc_) {
  # Convert the factor to numeric for processing
  if (is.factor(thc_)) {
    thc_ <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(thc_), "")))
  }

  # Create a matrix with the correc dimensions, and give names
  mat <- matrix(0, nrow = max(thc_) + 1, ncol = max(thc_) + 1)
  rownames(mat) <- colnames(mat) <- seq(min(thc_), max(thc_))

  # Add to the matrix when appropriate
  for (i in 1:(length(thc_) - 1)) {
    from = thc_[i] + 1
    to = thc_[i + 1] + 1
    mat[from, to] <- mat[from, to] + 1
  }
  return(mat)
}


## Build the activity matrix / node

build_node_df <- function(df_) {
  # get the maximum area length
  max_len <-
    max(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(
      as.character(df_$thc), ""
    ))))
  # Build the actual matrix function
  build_act_mat <- function(loc_, act_, max = max_len) {
    if (is.factor(loc_)) {
      loc_ <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(loc_), "")))
    }
    if (is.factor(act_)) {
      act_ <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(act_), "")))
    }
    area = rep(NA, max + 1)
    for (i in 1:length(loc_)) {
      area[loc_[i] + 1] <- act_[i]
    }
    return(area)
  }
  # Call the function
  out <- mapply(build_act_mat, df_$thc, df_$mdc)
  # cbind the output with the areas
  out <- data.frame(cbind(0:max_len, out))
  # Assign proper column names
  colnames(out) <- c("area", paste("mid_", df_$mid, sep = ""))
  return(out)
}
```

Then a function that applies those functions to the `df`, with some additions for your `hid` and `mid` output:

```
build_list <- function(dfo) {
  hid_ <- as.numeric(as.character(dfo$hid))
  mid_ <- as.numeric(as.character(dfo$mid))
  trip_ <- lapply(dfo$thc, build_adj_mat)
  node_ <- build_node_df(dfo)

  return(list(
    hid = hid_,
    mid = mid_,
    trip = trip_,
    node = node_)
    )
}
```

Output:

```
> build_list(df)
$hid
[1] 10001 10001 10001 10001

$mid
[1] 1 2 3 4

$trip
$trip[[1]]
  0 1
0 0 1
1 1 0

$trip[[2]]
  0 1
0 0 2
1 2 0

$trip[[3]]
  0
0 0

$trip[[4]]
  0 1 2 3
0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0


$node
  area mid_1 mid_2 mid_3 mid_4
1    0     0     0     0     0
2    1     0     1    NA    NA
3    2    NA    NA    NA     2
4    3    NA    NA    NA     2
```

I'm sure there's a way to get this to work with `dplyr`, but it's probably easier to just use `split` from base `R`. With this slightly modified dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  hid = c("10001", "10002", "10002", "10003"),
  mid = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  thc = c("010", "01010", "0", "02030"),
  mdc = c("000", "01010", "0", "02020")
)
```

Now split the new dataframe into a list and use `lapply` to apply the `build_list` function to each piece:

```
split_df2 <- split(df2, df2$hid)
names(split_df2) <- paste("hid_", names(split_df2), sep = "")
lapply(split_df2, build_list)
```

Output:

```
$hid_10001
$hid_10001$hid
[1] 10001

$hid_10001$mid
[1] 1

$hid_10001$trip
$hid_10001$trip[[1]]
  0 1
0 0 1
1 1 0


$hid_10001$node
  area mid_1
1    0     0
2    1     0


$hid_10002
$hid_10002$hid
[1] 10002 10002

$hid_10002$mid
[1] 2 3

$hid_10002$trip
$hid_10002$trip[[1]]
  0 1
0 0 2
1 2 0
...
...
```

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for your perfect idea! I will try to understand and apply it for my actual data frame. I will confirm how it works for multiple households data frame.